# MediaWiki API: Get images on a page and their URLs in one request?

Tags: mediawiki-api

Using just HTTPs requests, no wrapper, can I get a pages images and their URL's in a single request.

Right now, my workflow consists of two requests for each page (batched to two requests per ~50 pages). The first gets the page info and it's images:

```
prop=images|info&inprop=url
```

This gives me, among other things, a list of images that I can inspect to find which might be an image I want to link to. I also need the other bits of information, specifically normalized titles, titles and page urls. From there, I use the image title for a request to get it's hotlink URL:

```
prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url
```

Then I can finally get the image URL.

I want to be able to get the image URL in the first request, if possible. I've tried adding `imageinfo` to the `prop` item, but it doesn't give me anything new. I tried with `prop=pageimages`, but this only gives me one image per page, which may not be the image I want.

Must I make two whole requests just to get this info? The Wiki I'm trying to scrape doesn't have any extensions installed that I'm aware of (but I could get on the discord and try my luck at convincing the operators... maybe).

Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for `generator=images` ([doc](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators)). Try the [ApiSandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) for easier experimentation.

Comment: @Tgr That does give me the image URLs, but I lose the other page information (normalized titles, page titles, and page urls). I'll edit my question to say that I need this info.

Comment: You can still use `prop=imageinfo|info` or whatever. `generator` basically replaces `titles`.

Comment: @Tgr I tried with `prop=images|info&generator=image`, but the wiki only gave me the image pages. Then I tried with `generator=images|info`, but `info` can't be used as a generator.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=info%7Cimageinfo&titles=Portman%20Road&generator=images&inprop=url&iiprop=url

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve it using the following parameters:

```
generator=images, prop=imageinfo, iiprop=url
```

Example URL:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=images&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url&format=json&titles=heart
```